# How to show “Showing 1 of N Entries” with the dataTables.js library?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatable, datatables

```
var table = $("#user_table").DataTable({
    'sDom': '<"row-drop"<"col-sm-12 row"lr>><"row"t><"row-pager"<"col-sm-12 col-md-5"i><"col-sm-12"p>>',
    "ordering": true,
    "order": [[ 3, "asc" ]],
    "paging": true,
    "searching": true,
    "info": true,
    "autoWidth": false,
    "stateSave": true,
    "orderCellsTop": true,
    "fixedHeader": true,
```

This is my code. You can see this information : The value is true but also that div is disabled. Is there anyone who can help me. I would like to display the total number of entries visible in the datatable only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting bPaginate to false. The code you have works for version 1.10+, and bPaginate is what you use for version 1.9.

```
var table = $("#user_table").DataTable({
    'sDom': '<"row-drop"<"col-sm-12 row"lr>><"row"t><"row-pager"<"col-sm-12 col-md-5"i><"col-sm-12"p>>',
    "ordering": true,
    "order": [[ 3, "asc" ]],
    "bPaginate": false,
    "searching": true,
    "info": true,
    "autoWidth": false,
    "stateSave": true,
    "orderCellsTop": true,
    "fixedHeader": true,
```